# Script that will enter to each one of my directories and change a file name based on the directory name

Tags: terminal

I was wondering if you can help me with this little script.

I have 107 directories in my directory /html
In each one of those 107 directories I have a file named h.html
Can you guys help me making a script that will enter into each directory, and change h.html into DIRECTORYNAME.html

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Which language? Directory names contain slashes which are not allowed in filenames. What you would do in c# for example get a list of all files.. loop through list, get directory name for each entry, get file name for same entry, then make the filename the directory name, replacing forward slash with hyphen or other

Comment: in terminal! a linux shell